# Difficulty plotting a null cline

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, stability

### Problem Statement

Pplane produces this phase plane portrait:

[image: pplane raw]

Note the yellow line which represents the locus where $\dot{y}=0$.

My attempts to recreate this plot in Mathematica have failed.

[image: mm]

The vexatious piece is boxed below.

[image: vex]

---

### Question

How to plot the $y$ nullcline?

---

### Best effort

The differential equations are

```
xdot=4y^3+(x+1)-(x+1)((x+1)^2+y^4);

ydot=-2(x+1)+2y^3-2y^3 ((x+1)^2+y^4);
```

The nullcline components are computed using

```
Solve[ydot == 0, y];
nully = y /. %

{Root[1 + x + (2 x + x^2) #1^3 + #1^7 &, 1], 
 Root[1 + x + (2 x + x^2) #1^3 + #1^7 &, 2], 
 Root[1 + x + (2 x + x^2) #1^3 + #1^7 &, 3], 
 Root[1 + x + (2 x + x^2) #1^3 + #1^7 &, 4], 
 Root[1 + x + (2 x + x^2) #1^3 + #1^7 &, 5], 
 Root[1 + x + (2 x + x^2) #1^3 + #1^7 &, 6], 
 Root[1 + x + (2 x + x^2) #1^3 + #1^7 &, 7]}
```

The problematic component is the first element:

[image: trouble]

The other elements were successful:

```
gya = Plot[nully[[2]], {x, -\[Lambda], \[Lambda]},PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}}, PlotPoints -> 1500];

gyc = Plot[nully[[1]], {x, -1.265, \[Lambda]},PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}}, PlotPoints -> 1500];

Show[{gya, gyc}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: aandc]

Comment: `ContourPlot[-2 (x + 1) + 2 y^3 - 2 y^3 ((x + 1)^2 + y^4) == 0, {x, -4,
   4}, {y, -4, 4}]`

Comment: @Alan. Wonderful. Intuitive and much simpler. Please promote this to an answer for up voting.

Comment: The answer in the proposed duplicate uses `ContourPlot` to plot the nullclines. This is what Alan also suggested here. I have not tried it, but you indicated that it also works for your, less well behaved, system. If the solution is the same, then I think it is fair to say that they are duplicates. If you disagree, please state why you are dissatisfied with `ContourPlot`.

Comment: @ C. E.: You are entirely correct. An up vote to you.